# Encounter errors when create react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When I try to run `npm create-react-app <name>`, I encounter error reports. I've tried updating my node.js/npm and several other things and just don't work.

[image]

Comment: Try `npx create-react-app appname` or `npm init react-app appname`

Answer (score 1):

as you see in the error message, you have to install the last version of Visual Studio, take a look at [node-gyp README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows), there is a guide to install and configure the dependencies.

suggest: use the `npx` to initialize a new react project with CRA, this way you will install the latest version each time.

Comment: npm ERR! Warning: Missing input files:
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libintl-8.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgthread-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll